# What does the German say in the opening of ef - a tale of melodies?

Tags: theme-song, ef-a-fairy-tale-of-the-two

The OP sequences for ef - a tale of melodies have a lot of German text in the background. The text seems to be the same for all of the different versions. This version is from episode 6, and features the instrumental version of the song (Ebullient Future) and the characters are not present, so it's the easiest to read the text:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRp0Adtwadc&hd=1

I think it's pretty safe to assume this isn't totally random German text. What does it say (in English), and what is it referencing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the entire OP has been translated [in this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20120716191313/http://www.aquastar-anime.net/?page=articles/article20081211). It says that the lines are from 2 different EF related songs, "Eternal Feather" from the ending theme of the last episode of "ef - a tale of memories" and "Emotional Flutter" from the opening of the game "ef - a latter tale".

The article has all of the text, side-by-side, with the English translation and (in red) the song that the line came from. There's also a note at the end about some names of other EF related songs on-screen.

> Holding the reviving memories [Eternal Feather]
> To my chest [Eternal Feather]
> There was a distant sky on the other side of the window [Eternal Feather]
> I was watching the unreachable clouds [Eternal Feather]
> The smile left behind on the road home, [Emotional Flutter]
> Will never find the voice it looks for [Emotional Flutter]
> The darkness engraved in my memories [Emotional Flutter]
> Even now, won't end [Emotional Flutter]
> Even now, won't end [Emotional Flutter]
> Swooping down from the sky, [Emotional Flutter]
> There was a distant sky on the other side of the window [Eternal Feather]
> I was watching the unreachable clouds [Eternal Feather]
> My breaking heart has been healed [Eternal Feather]
> I heard a tender voice [Eternal Feather]
> Pieces of a dream spill and fall into my palms [Eternal Feather]
> To search for the lost answer, I start running [Eternal Feather]
> Overcoming the time when we came across each other [Eternal Feather]
> Our hands join together [Eternal Feather]
> Holding the reviving memories [Eternal Feather]
> To my chest [Eternal Feather]
> I search for your back that I have forgotten about [Eternal Feather]
> Making the loneliness end [Eternal Feather]
> I believe you, but I feel uneasy [Eternal Feather]
> And I dreamed of your voice [Eternal Feather]
> I fear getting hurt [Eternal Feather]
> and make my face smile, [Eternal Feather]
> I'll start weaving a breakable courage, if we're together [Eternal Feather]
> When I change even the pain frozen onto me into warmth [Eternal Feather]
> The sound of the bell echoes [Eternal Feather]
> Into the endless future [Eternal Feather]
> Soar up high into the sky [Eternal Feather]
> Even if you don't have feathers [Eternal Feather]
> I believe you, but I feel uneasy [Eternal Feather]
> And I dreamed of your voice [Eternal Feather]
> The smile left behind on the road home [Emotional Flutter]
> Will never find the voice it looks for [Emotional Flutter]
> The darkness engraved in my memories even now, won't end [Emotional Flutter]
> Even now, won't end [Emotional Flutter]
> Swooping down from the sky, [Emotional Flutter]
> The white wings swayed [Emotional Flutter]
> Running with my outstretched hand, [Emotional Flutter]
> I chased after your shadow [Emotional Flutter]
> If the falling white snow were to pile up, [Emotional Flutter]
> It would cover up these sad colors [Emotional Flutter]
> The love sleeping deep within my heart [Emotional Flutter]
> Please remember it [Emotional Flutter]
> Soar high up in the sky [Emotional Flutter]
> And spread your wings [Emotional Flutter]
> Inside the gentle rays of the sun [Emotional Flutter]
> You showed me your dreams [Emotional Flutter]
> Fluttering down from the high sky, [Emotional Flutter]
> Wear your white wings [Emotional Flutter]
> Our joined hands [Emotional Flutter]
> Won't let go of the future [Emotional Flutter]
> The love sleeping deep within my heart [Emotional Flutter]
> Please remember it [Emotional Flutter]
> The smile left behind on the road home [Emotional Flutter]
> Will never find the voice it looks for [Emotional Flutter]
> The darkness engraved in my memories even now, won't end [Emotional Flutter]
> Even now, won't end [Emotional Flutter]
> There was a distant sky on the other side of the window [Eternal Feather]
> I was watching the unreachable clouds [Eternal Feather]
> My breaking heart has been healed [Eternal Feather]
> I heard a tender voice [Eternal Feather]
> Swooping down from the sky, [Emotional Flutter]
> The white wings swayed [Emotional Flutter]
> Pieces of a dream spill and fall into my palms [Eternal Feather]
> To search for the lost answer, I start running [Eternal Feather]
> Overcoming the time when we came across each other [Eternal Feather]
> Our hands join together [Eternal Feather]
> Holding the reviving memories [Eternal Feather]
> To my chest [Eternal Feather]
> Running with my outstretched hand, [Emotional Flutter]
> I chased after your shadow [Emotional Flutter]
> I search for your back that I have forgotten about [Eternal Feather]
> Making the loneliness end [Eternal Feather]